# Adding a dialog XUL in addition to an overlay in Firefox extension

Tags: dialog, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to add a dialog box using XUL to a Firefox extension that already has an overlay xul defined.  I tried adding the dialog code in the same overlay.xul file, but run into a "dialog.getButton is not a function" error in the Error Console.   The structure of the file looks like this:

```xml
<overlay id="xxx" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
... code...
<dialog id="yyy" 
   buttons=","
   onload="onLoad();">
   ....
 </dialog>
 </overlay>
```

If I separate out the dialog xul code into a different file, then everything seems to work.  The difference is that in the separate dialog.xul file, the dialog code looks like this:

```xml
<dialog id=yyy" 
   xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
   buttons=","
   onload="onLoad();">
   ...
</dialog>
```

Is it possible or correct to add the dialog code in the same overlay XUL file or should I actually separate them?  Is it ok to have multiple XUL files for the same extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible or correct to add the dialog code in the same overlay XUL file

No.

> should I actually separate them?

Yes.

> Is it ok to have multiple XUL files for the same extension?

Yes.

You can have as many XUL files in your extension as you want. Each XUL document should be in a separate file - already because the root tag of the document matters. An overlay should have `<overlay>` as its root tag, a dialog needs to use the root tag `<dialog>` and a regular window `<window>`.

Comment: Thank you!  Will proceed on this direction!